# Multiplos Models numa view Asp.Net MVC c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, view, controller

Estou com uma questão a um mês. Tenho 2 tabelas ou Models e pretendo que na view elas sejam manipuladas, como: visualizar seus dados visto que saem da BD e tambem Inserir dados nas mesmas tabelas. Vi muitas dicas mas nenhuma foi completa. Alguem pode me ajudar?

Comment: Qual código você fez até o momento?

Comment: namespace projecto.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    
    public partial class usuarios
    {
        public string usuario { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime nascimento { get; set; }
        public string Bilhete{ get; set; }
       
     
    }
}

Comment: criei uma ViewModel assim using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace projecto.Models
{
    public class geral
    {
        public usuarios Usuarios{ get; set; }
        public List<usuarios> Lista_Usuarios { get; set; }


        public produtos Produto { get; set; }
        public List<produto> Lista_Produtos { get; set; }

    }
}